# Dynamic layout with relativeLayouts and a textView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

i have a layout with 2 relativeLayouts on the side and a textView on the middle.

Something like this:

RL || TEXTVIEW || RL

Now, my problem is that everything have a dynamic size, the 2 relativeLayouts have to have always present on the layout and the textview have to be in the center and have to occupy all the space left between both RL. The textView can't be on top or bottom of any of the relativeLayouts.

All of this have to be done using xml. Any Sugestion? Thanks!

Comment: Some things that i have tried goes form having a relativelayout and all the objects referencing to the one before with "toLeftOf", this make the second RL goes out the screen. 
I also tried to put both RL align to the left and the right, and on the TV i put toRightOf the RL of the left and teh opposite to the right side, this makes the TV to collapse between both RL (since the second one fills the hole line).
Other thing that i tried was to use weights but i end up with to much space free on some occasions (since i don't know the size of the RLs and the TV).

Comment: You can add the RLs with alignPanrentLeft and alignParentRight, and the textview with toLeftOf and toRightOf. However, if the RLs overlap, then you are in trouble (:

Comment: @SherifelKhatib thanks for your help. That was one of my tries, it didn't work because i had the second RL with widht="wrap_content" and that made it to occupy all the line, so the TV collapsed between the RLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to do this i used layout_weights on all the views, and putted a width of 0dp on all views.